# datetime to string with series in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

How should I transform from `datetime` to `string`? My attempt:

```
dates = p.to_datetime(p.Series(['20010101', '20010331']), format = '%Y%m%d')
dates.str
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

There is no `.str` accessor for datetimes and you can't do `.astype(str)` either.

Instead, use [`.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
>>> series = pd.Series(['20010101', '20010331'])
>>> dates = pd.to_datetime(series, format='%Y%m%d')
>>> dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
0    2001-01-01
1    2001-03-31
dtype: object
```

See the docs on customizing date string formats here: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

---

For old pandas versions `<0.17.0`, one can instead can call `.apply` with the Python standard library's `datetime.strftime`:

```
>>> dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
0    2001-01-01
1    2001-03-31
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. But now I found another problem. If a have NaT.? How to solve it ?  `dates = p.to_datetime(p.Series(['20010101', '20010331',None]), format = '%Y%m%d')
dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: Drop them first is one option so `dates.dropna().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: @EdChum This still doesn't turn dates into strings. `type(dates.df.strftime(...))` says `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. You need to add `.tolist()`. pandas version 0.25.3

Answer (score 51):

[As of pandas version 0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-strftime), you can format with the `dt` accessor:

```
dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: this sped up my code 10 fold compared to using `datetime.strftime` inside a lambda function in a dataframe `.apply()` method (as suggested by @EdChum)

Answer (score 3):

There is a pandas function that can be applied to DateTime index in pandas data frame.

```
date = dataframe.index #date is the datetime index
date = dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #this will return you a numpy array, element is string.
dstr = date.tolist() #this will make you numpy array into a list
```

the element inside the list:

```
u'1910-11-02'
```

You might need to replace the 'u'.

There might be some additional arguments that I should put into the previous functions.