# Pandas: How can I convert 'timestamp' values in my dataframe column from object/str to timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning, data-scrubbing

My timestamp looks like below in the dataframe of my column but it is in 'object'. I want to convert this into 'timestamp'. How can I convert all values such in my dataframe column into timestamp?

```
0    01/Jul/1995:00:00:01
1    01/Jul/1995:00:00:06
2    01/Jul/1995:00:00:09
3    01/Jul/1995:00:00:09
4    01/Jul/1995:00:00:09
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

I tried below code referring this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime) but it gives me error:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Below is the error:

```
ValueError: time data '01/Jul/1995:00:00:01' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)
```

Comment: Show us the error you get.

Comment: I have added error in question now, I get value error of format not matching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the follwing format:

```
ourdates = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is working, however is there any way I can keep month names: July, Jan, Feb, etc.

Comment: @JubinSoni when you convert the string to a datetime object you can output that in whatever format you please. Could be Jul, 07, or July.

Comment: But my output now is this: 1995-07-01 00:00:01 and I want '01/Jul/1995 00:00:01'. I tried doing %m instead of %b in format but that gives error.

Comment: @JubinSoni ok I think this is a separate question to this, but you should find the answer to your second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas