# Apply .str operation on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel dump which has 50+ columns with either dates or blank cells. When I read these excels in python they appear as dates with time stamp. Thus I tried to split every cell and convert into a string using a for loop -

```
for all in df2:
    df2['all'] = df2['all'].astype(str).str[0:10]
```

however this is not working - any suggestions how to go about.

Comment: u posted a suggestion - sf2 = sf2.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str[:10]) - this works perfect however for loop is not working well as it is copying split values into another columns. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through your columns using the `all` variable you define, but within your loop you use `all` within quotes - making it a string, thus it would only act on the column named 'all'.

```
for all in df2:
    df2[all] = df2[all].astype(str).str[0:10]
```

Answer (score -1):

pandas has a [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function where you can specify the output format 
`dateData=pd.to_datetime(df2, format = '%Y%m%d')` may work.
and if you want to convert to string you can use [strftime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime)

there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas)

Comment: well i get the error - 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'stfrtime'

Comment: what I tried: `test = pandas.read_excel("path\Test.xls")
truc=pandas.to_datetime(test["nameColumn1"],format="%Y%M%D")
bidule=truc.dt.strftime(date_format="%Y-%m-%d")` it works in my case 
>>> type(test)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
>>> type(truc)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> >>> type(bidule[0])
<class 'str'>

Comment: to do all columns in one time:
`df1 = pd.read_excel("file.xls")
truc=df1.values 
test=pd.to_datetime(numpy.squeeze(truc[:]))
resultat =  test.strftime(data_format="%Y-%m-%d")`