# Converting dataframe column of datetime data to DD/MM/YYYY string data

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with datetime data in `1980-12-11T00:00:00` format.

I need to convert the whole column to `DD/MM/YYY` string format.

Is there any easy code for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas So something like dates.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('1980-12-11T00:00:00').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` : `'11/12/1980'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1980-12-11T00:00:00', '1990-12-11T00:00:00', '2000-12-11T00:00:00']})
print(df)

                  date
0  1980-12-11T00:00:00
1  1990-12-11T00:00:00
2  2000-12-11T00:00:00
```

Convert the column to `datetime` by [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and invoke [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
df['date_new']=pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(df)

                  date    date_new
0  1980-12-11T00:00:00  11/12/1980
1  1990-12-11T00:00:00  11/12/1990
2  2000-12-11T00:00:00  11/12/2000
```

Comment: I am getting: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 7020-11-11 00:00:00

Comment: No, definitely not the year. The format of the date before converting to string is YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00

Comment: exactly ` 7020-11-11 00:00:00` this line is where the error is occurring. :) since pandas cant 7020 as year

Comment: ah, its a problem with the data! Is there any way to not stop on errors like that?

Comment: @Bimons you can check this and other related links. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert string to datetime data

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
```

You can also pass specific format as:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `pandas`, try `pandas.to_datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1980-12-%sT00:00:00'%i for i in range(10,20)]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)
         date
0  10/12/1980
1  11/12/1980
2  12/12/1980
3  13/12/1980
4  14/12/1980
5  15/12/1980
6  16/12/1980
7  17/12/1980
8  18/12/1980
9  19/12/1980
```