# How to change datetime format of different dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

This question is related to the thread
[How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

The solutions presented there work fine for one date, but what if you have different dates in the same dataframe?

For instance, my dates in datetime are

```
2016-01-26
2016-01-27
2016-01-28
2016-01-29
```

Code as in the other thread where the same date is used twice:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016', 1: '26/1/2016'}})
print (df)
         DOB
0  26/1/2016 
1  26/1/2016

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)
print (df)
         DOB
0 2016-01-26
1 2016-01-26

df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
         DOB        DOB1
0 2016-01-26  01/26/2016
1 2016-01-26  01/26/2016
```

I also found this code on (I think it was) [datetime to string with series in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas)

```
df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

And this one:

```
df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].map(lambda x:x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

For instance in my dataframe DOB I have the following dates and would like to have them in a different format.

My dates in Datetime format:

```
0  2016-01-26
1  2016-01-27
2  2016-01-28  
3  2016-01-29
```

Desired output:

```
01/26/2016
01/27/2016
01/28/2016
01/29/2016
```

I've been using the same codes as above but when I run them (no matter which of the codes) ALL the dates get turned into

```
01/26/2016
01/26/2016
01/26/2016
01/26/2016
```

It seems like pandas takes the first value and applies it to the rest of the dataframe. How can I make pandas read and convert each of the dates differently?

Thank you!

Comment: can we see the exact code you used to convert your 2nd code block to your 3rd code block

Answer (score 0):

I run your code, and the results are as you expected.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016', 1: '27/1/2016', 2: '28/1/2016'}})
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)
df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Result:

```
         DOB        DOB1
0 2016-01-26  01/26/2016
1 2016-01-27  01/27/2016
2 2016-01-28  01/28/2016
```

Without knowing more details, I would suggest you create a function and apply it to your column.

```
convert_date = lambda i: i.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df['DOB'].apply(convert_date)

0    01/26/2016
1    01/27/2016
2    01/28/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking into this. I caught my mistake and it's kind of embarrasing but I do want to leave the question in here - also to show other beginners where you can go wrong without catching the mistake at first. I also owe the kind persons who provided a reply an explanation.

It's true that I actually did use the above code as an example. BUT in my code I forgot to include %d in strftime. So, of course dates like

```
2016-01-26
2016-01-27
2016-01-28
2016-01-29
```

would be converted to

```
2016\01
2016\01
2016\01
2016\01
```

However, only when N. Arunoprayoch replied did I see it!!!  I wonder how I could I miss that??

Sorry about that and thanks again for your help!