# invalid type comparison when using np.where?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code:

```
 Depth['timing']=np.where((Depth['time_entry']== 'later' )| (Depth['offer_status']=='market'), Depth['time_status_change'],Depth['time_entry'])
    Depth2['timing']=np.where((Depth2['time_entry']== 'later' ) | (Depth2['offer_status']=='market'), Depth2['time_status_change'],Depth2['time_entry'])
```

**Update:** I solved it anyways, but used some stupid loop which is not very good for performance.

What I got is: `invalid type comparison` . What can I do to fix it? `Depth['time_entry']` is a column with either a `number` or `'later'`, so maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Please share some example data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with converting `Depth['time_entry']` in to string first and then validating against `'later'`.

See this: [datetime to string with series in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas).