# How to convert datetime column to string column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I can convert string column to datetime column;
`pd.to_datetime(data['Document Date'])` .
But how to convert datetime to string back again?

Comment: `data['Document Date'] = data['Document Date'].astype(str)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime to string with series in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas)

Comment: `df["datetime_col"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

`data['Document Date'] = data.apply(lambda x: str(x))` should work.

If your string was formatted in a different way than the default representation of a date in pandas, then you won't be able to convert back to the original string format: that data is lost in the conversion. If this is the case, I recommend you simply create a new column that stores the converted datetime, alongside the existing string column.