# Datetime not showing in specified format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
import fxcmpy
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

end = datetime.datetime.today()
today = date.today()
data = con.get_candles(ticker, period='D1', start = start, end = end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%B-%d')
data = data.set_index(data.index.normalize())
data = data.reindex(full_dates)
```

When i print `data`

i get this:

```
    bidopen bidclose    bidhigh bidlow  askopen askclose    askhigh asklow  tickqty
2008-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2008-01-02  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2008-01-03  13261.82    13043.96    13279.54    12991.37    13261.82    13043.96    13279.54    12991.37    0.0
2008-01-04  13044.12    13056.72    13137.93    13023.56    13044.12    13056.72    13137.93    13023.56    0.0
2008-01-05  13046.56    12800.18    13046.72    12789.04    13046.56    12800.18    13046.72    12789.04    0.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2019-12-19  28272.45    28401.75    28414.05    28245.65    28277.00    28405.45    28418.65    28248.35    378239.0
2019-12-20  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-21  28401.60    28472.20    28518.80    28369.90    28405.30    28474.30    28520.30    28371.30    513987.0
2019-12-22  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-23  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4375 rows × 9 columns
```

My question is that since the format i had used was `format ='%Y-%B-%d'` for the date why is it not showing in that format?

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you were using in 'data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%B-%d')' was used to interpret the data in index as datetime. To display the output you will need something like `data.index.dt.strftime('%Y-%B%-%d')`.