# Extracting Dates into Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I would like to take a date range in python, than create a new series/column the has the date formatted as a string as `YYYYMMDD`

This is what I have so far:

```
start = '20200214' # YYYYMMDD
end = '20200216' # YYYYMMDD

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start,end).date),columns = ['dates'])
dates['Year'] = dates['dates'].dt.year
dates['Month'] = dates['dates'].dt.month
dates['Day'] = dates['dates'].dt.day
```

I tried to add each element as a string, `dates.Year.astype(str) + dates.Month.astype(str)+...`, but I need leading zeros.

So take the first date, `2020-02-14` and change it to `20200214`. Then rinse and repeat for all others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime to string with series in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of resources on the subject, including the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dates['reformatted_date'] = dates['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
       dates  Year  Month  Day reformatted_date
0 2020-02-14  2020      2   14         20200214
1 2020-02-15  2020      2   15         20200215
2 2020-02-16  2020      2   16         20200216
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is possible with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
dates['Year'] = dates['dates'].dt.year
dates['Month'] = dates['dates'].dt.month
dates['Day'] = dates['dates'].dt.day
dates['dates1'] = (dates.Year.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + 
                   dates.Month.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + 
                   dates['Day'].astype(str))
```

But simplier and faster is use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
dates['dates2'] = dates['dates'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print (dates)
       dates  Year  Month  Day    dates1    dates2
0 2020-02-14  2020      2   14  20200214  20200214
1 2020-02-15  2020      2   15  20200215  20200215
2 2020-02-16  2020      2   16  20200216  20200216
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "{:02d}".format(1)
'01'
>>> "{:02d}".format(12)
'12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where` checking for the condition whether it is less than `10` and adding the 0 or not:

```
dates['final'] = dates['Year'].astype(str) + np.where(dates['Month'] < 10,"0"+dates['Month'].astype(str),dates['Month'].astype(str))+ np.where(dates['Day'] < 10,"0"+dates['Day'].astype(str),dates['Day'].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this option:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
c = str(d)[0:10] //to string
print(c.replace('-', '')) 
//data comes in this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
//output yyyymmdd
```

or this:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
c = d.isoformat() //to string
e = c[0:10]
print (e.replace('-', ''))
//data comes in this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
//output yyyymmdd
```