# Pandas df with datetime64 type, display as just Year month day e.g. '2021-01-01'

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

A data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')], ['nick', 15, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')], ['juli', 14, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'date'])
```

Here's how it looks in pycharm:
[image]

It includes the time part `00:00:00`. This is relevant because when I try to display in a datatable with Dash, it displays with this part. So I want to get rid of the time part and show just the date part.

Here's the .info:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Name    3 non-null      object        
 1   Age     3 non-null      int64         
 2   date    3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

I would like to convert date to just a string of the form '2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'.

Tried:

```
df['newdate'] = df['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5460, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

How can I reformat df['date'] to be a string of the form '2021-01-01', that is '%Y-%m-%d'?

Comment: You need `.dt`: `df['newdate'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: is `dt` reference to a package or a method?

Comment: `dt` refers to [the accessor object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) exclusive to Pandas' datetime Series.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: im pretty sure you can also use dt.date as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime to string with series in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-python-pandas)