# How to convert a Python Pandas DateTime Object to a string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains 'Report Date' in datetime format. The df contains a single record.  I want to get just the string value. This is what I am using:

```
report_date = df['Report Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
report_date
```

which produces this output:

```
0    2021-06-30

Name: Report Date, dtype: object
```

How do I get to a variable that is just the string "2021-06-30" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime to string with series in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
report_date = df['Report Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
report_date = report_date[0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).